# Finding the orders of elements of $GL(3, \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

I'm trying to find orders of elements of $G = GL(3, \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$, I understand it has an element of order $7$. How about $8$ or $9$? I know the minimal polynomial of such a matrix divides $x^8 -1$, and minimal polynomial can't be $x-1$ or $(x-1)^2$. If minimal polynomial is $(x-1)^3$, and since the characteristic polynomial is of order $3$. In this case characteristic polynomial = minimal polynomial = $(x-1)^3 = x^3 + x^2 + x + 1$. Following this direction, such matrices I found are of order $4$. I think I must have done something wrong in the process. Maybe $G$ does not have elements of order $8$?

Comment: quick computation tells me that $G$ only has elements of order $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$, $7$. So no elements of order 8 i'm afraid

Comment: In `sagemath`, `G = GL(3, GF(2)); for elt in G: print elt.order()`, or even `s = set(); for elt in G: s.add(elt.order()); print s`

Comment: But what's wrong with my reasoning? And for which n do you think G will have elements of order 8?

Comment: honestly, i'm still trying to work through what your reasoning is (it's quite late, and i'm not at my sharpest, also have little interaction with finite fields or these sorts of groups normally). I did however see that it is finite, so just ran over to sagemath. I can also confirm that the $4 \times 4$ case also has no elements of order $8$

Comment: Do you know how to find the order of the group? It's $(2^3 - 2^0)(2^3 - 2^1)(2^3 - 2^2) = 7 \cdot 6 \cdot 4 = 2^3 \cdot 3 \cdot 7$, which rules out elements of order $9$. Unfortunately I'm very rusty with polynomials associated with matrices, so I can't comment on that.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be the set of nonzero vectors of $\mathbb{F}_2^3$. Since $G$ acts on $X$ and $|X|=7$, no element can have an $8$-cycle or higher in its cycle decomposition, which precludes one from having order $8$.

---

With minimal polynomials: if $(x-1)^3$ were the minimal polynomial of an element in $G$, then the polynomial $(x-1)^4=x^4-1$ would vanish at it, i.e. it'd have order dividing $4$.

Comment: I'm trying to see it from minimal polynomial and characteristic polynomial viewpoint. What's preventing $(x-1)^3$ from being minimal polynomial? I think if that's the case the char polynomial could be $(x-1)^5$. And $n = 5$ could give an element of order 8.

Comment: @nico23 You already pointed out in your question the char poly has order $3$, so I'm not sure where you're getting $5$ from. Anyway, I added an argument about the min poly.

Comment: My question was edited I didn't notice. I originally asked about $GL(n, Z/2)$. Sorry about the confusion.